# Object changed by another thread

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multithreading, thread-safety

This problem is encountered in part of a complicated system where many threads need to access to the same method. This project is written in C#. To simplify the problem, I use the following illustration:

I have two customised classes, the parent class of these two classes is the same. The two classes are Apple and Orange, the parent is Fruit. The problem came when I expect an apple, but it is actually an Orange. **This happens sometimes, not not a rare event, probably 10% of the time.**

```
public void MethodAlpha(object food)
{
   lock(this)
   {
       FoodObj foodObj = Converter.XMLStringToObject(food, ...) //"food" is a string

       if(foodObj.FoodType == StringConstants.Apple)
       {
           Apple apple = (Apple)foodObj.FoodObject; <--InvaildCastException
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

The InvaildCastException says I am trying to cast an Orange to an Apple, when I have already handled it by "lock(this)" and the if checking. Have I handled it incorrectly? How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems to modify `FoodType` instead, so I guess the error is in the data it's receiving.

Comment: Unless `Converter.XMLStringToObject` has some internal state you haven't told us about, this isn't anything to do with threading.

Comment: Definitely nothing to do with Converter.XMLStringToObject, i think u all are on the wrong track. Converter.XMLStringToObject is from a library that is used in many projects here.

Comment: so you say; yet I've asked you many times to clarify some issues about the usage, even on the subject of threaded usage (in particular, does `XMLStringToObject` use fields, how many instances of the thing-that-declares-`MethodAlpha` etc) - and you haven't provided that info. This stuff matters. The code in your question ***has zero capacity, in itself, for threading bugs***. It might, *in combination* with context that you haven't told us, but we aren't psychic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say `food` is a `string`; now, `string`s are immutable, so *that* hasn't changed during the method - and the parameter `food` is not by-ref (`ref`), so *that* hasn't changed during the method.

`Converter.XMLStringToObject` *appears* (hard to say) to parse the string to an object, so there is no shared state there unless you have some cache that you haven't told us about.

So... this is just a parsing bug in your code; nothing to do with threading.

Note: method parameters and variables are *per call* - they are isolated (unless they refer to shared state).

This is not a threading issue. Just a run-of-the-mill bug. At some point during parsing, you've *called* it an apple, but assigned it an orange. Trace through `XMLStringToObject` to find it, looking in particular at where `.FoodType` and `FoodObject` get assigned.

As an aside - `lock(this)` is a bad idea *in general*; in this case, it also does nothing useful since you have no shared state to protect. If there *was* a use, having a dedicated object for this would be preferred:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
...
lock(syncLock) {...}
```

Comment: No, this is a threading issue. He is using 'this' to lock with, and since the method is called from different threads, the 'this' instances will be different. So no lock. Your aside is actually the correct answer :-) I agree, though, that the string typeinfo is slightly mysterious and probably could be done better.

Comment: @AHM - `this` doesn't depend on the thread; it depends on the object being invoked, i.e. the `obj` in `obj.MethodAlpha(...)`. Any threads talking to the same object will therefore hit the same lock. And without evidence of shared state, any discussion of a threading bug is pointless. THERE IS NOTHING TO CORRUPT, otherwise. Changing between `this` and a dedicated lock object is a purity thing; it will not change the behaviour except in the edge-case that something else (external) is using that object for a sync-lock.

Comment: No, sorry that was a silly comment. I don't know how I missed that the XMLStingToObject function assigned it's results to a local variable. Obviously, no other thread is changing that. Though, maybe something is changing the shared string before it can correctly make an apple, but after is has read the typeinfo? Anyway you are completely correct the problem must be in the convert function.

Comment: Maybe the original poster could correct me, but I read it as the incoming 'food' object is somehow shared between threads and then passed by reference. Otherwise the lock is completely pointless.

Comment: @AHM - but he notes that `food` is actually a string... and unless you go to extreme lengths, strings are immutable...

Comment: Converter.XMLStringToObject has no bug, it is from a library used in many of the projects. The method basically uses XmlSerializer

Comment: @yeeen how to say this nicely... the code shown *also* has no bug; and certainly nothing threading related. Either `XMLStringToObject` has a bug, or you have screwy data. Meant in a positive way, but maybe you mean "has no bug that I know of" - the problem is, we rarely know about bugs until we find them. I would happily scan it to see, but I can't do much without `XMLStringToObject`.

Comment: @yeeen of course, the bug could also be in `FoodObj`, or in some obscure scenario (not shown) where `FoodObj` goes via an identity-map; but there is ***nothing*** in the code shown that can *possibly* be subject to threading. All the values are local to that stack-frame. Threading is a complete non-issue inside a stack-frame.

Comment: @yeeen - as an example, if `XMLStringToObject` uses local *fields* (not method variables), then that won't be thread-safe. You only lock against the current instance of whatever-declares-`MethodAlpha`, but if you have multiple instances, they won't be mutually exclusive between different objects. Hence that could cause problems. But since you don't give any of that context, it is hard to advise.

Comment: The 'apple' is a newly created method variable, isn't it? The context is receiving message from Java Messaging Systems and processing it. I can't provide the original code. Would that be enough for you to give advice?

Comment: @yeeen `apple` is indeed a local method variable, but that is just the reference; the actual *object* comes from `foodObj.FoodObject`. There is simply no detail in the question that helps, I'm afraid. Of course, the `...` in the question could *also* be relevant if the `...` includes a capture into a lambda or anonymous-method.

Comment: @yeeen if the problem is actually related to fields on `XMLStringToObject `, and if `Converter` is a reference (not a static type), you could also try `lock(Converter) {...}` instead of `lock(this) {...}`. And if the problem is static fields, a single static sync-lock might help (`private static readonly object syncLock = new object(); ... lock(syncLock) {...}`

Comment: Found the cause of the prob, it is related to static fields in the apple object... Hv to make it non-static. sorry for the trouble. Thanks. .

Comment: @yeeen - there we go; making it non-static gives you the best ability to scale, but if that isn't possible using a static lock object (as mentioned previously) is a workaround.

Comment: But i actually tried before using a 'private static' object to lock that piece of code, it didn't work. Is 'readonly' a must?

Answer (score 0):

As Marc Gravell suggested use a separate Object instance for lock purpose and to get rid of the exception

```
Apple apple = foodObj.FoodObject as Apple;

if(apple != null)
{
 // do something here
}
```

Comment: casting away the unexpected apple vs orange doesn't really locate the underlying bug. If he is expecting an apple... then he is expecting an apple.